# Migrate Expo to monorepo cause "Invalid hook call" error

Tags: expo, monorepo, pnpm

I have an Expo app, created a few years ago and running in production.

Today I want to migrate this app in a monorepo, handled with **PNPM workspaces**, with others app (NestJS, React, ...) sharing the sames custom librairies.

All my apps works fine, except my Expo app. When I try to run it with Expo Go or development build, I got this error :

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

But I didn't edit my code so I know it works, cause it's in production.

From my research, I put a `.npmrc` file on my monorepo's root with this this instruction : `node-linker=hoisted`.
Also I've created a `metro.config.js` file with this content :

```js
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');
const path = require('path');

const projectRoot = __dirname;
const monorepoRoot = path.resolve(projectRoot, '../..');

const config = getDefaultConfig(projectRoot);

config.watchFolders = [monorepoRoot];
config.resolver.nodeModulesPaths = [
  path.resolve(projectRoot, 'node_modules'),
  path.resolve(monorepoRoot, 'node_modules'),
];

module.exports = config;
```

And changed the entrypoint of my app in my `package.json` to point to a new `index.ts` file with this content :

```
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import App from './App';

registerRootComponent(App);
```

I think I've followed required steps from official documentation : https://docs.expo.dev/guides/monorepos/

But still not works.

I found some issues saying it can be a conflict between different versions of react on the same project, but *react* and *react-dom* are installed on the Expo application's `node_modules` to override any other versions.

I'm not very familiar with monorepos, put I think it's sufficient, isn't it ?

Thank's for your help.